# MouseClick coordinates appear only for the first time, always the same for others

Tags: java, swing

I am making a program which draws circles in the clicked place.

For the first click it draws circle which is not exactly in the same place I have clicked.

But furthermore, for other clicks it just draws circles one on the other. as i find out it is because the coordinates of click won't change.

my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   //set window size
   frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
   //set the title
   frame.setTitle("Oval Draw");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   //add panel to frame and make it visible
   MouseComponent component = new MouseComponent();
   frame.add(component);
   frame.setVisible(true);        
}
```

and the MouseComponent class:

```
public class MouseComponent extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
        boolean drawPoint = true;
        boolean drawLine = false;
        boolean drawOval = false;

    public MouseComponent()
    {
        super();
        pointX = 0;
        pointY = 0;   
        lineX = 0;
        lineY = 0;
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    int pointX, pointY, lineX, lineY;
    int[] ArrayX,ArrayY;         

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
             if(drawLine)
            {
                int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                Color startrandomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

                red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                Color endrandomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
               // this.addMouseListener(this);
                GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70, 70, startrandomColor,
                150, 150, endrandomColor);

                g2d.setPaint(gradient);
                g2d.translate( lineX, lineY);
                g2d.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
                System.out.print(lineX);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(lineY);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(pointX);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(pointY);
                System.out.print(" ");
                // repaint();
            }
            else if(drawPoint)
            {
              //  g.drawOval(pointX-5,pointY-5,10,10);
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse)
    {
        if(!drawPoint)    
        {
        pointX = mouse.getX();
        pointY = mouse.getY();
        drawPoint = true;   
        }    

        else if(!drawLine)   
        {
        lineX = mouse.getX();
        lineY = mouse.getY();
        drawLine = true;    
        }
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouse){ }   
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouse){ }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouse){ }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouse){ }
}
```

Comment: So for the first look you declare the booleans `drawPoint` and `drawLine`. on the MouseEvent you have a negative test on these booleans. in the first click he will go into the drawLine because false becomes true and other way around for drawPoint. After that both will evaluate to true and get to false in the MouseEvent. You don't get new X and Y as it seems.

Comment: Beyond that: you want others to spend their time to help you. So you please spend the time to format/indent **all** of your source code nicely.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

This here:

```
 if(!drawPoint)    
    {
    pointX = mouse.getX();
    pointY = mouse.getY();
    drawPoint = true;   
    }
```

simply doesn't make too much sense. You init drawPoint to `true` ... so you will **never** enter the if block and collect the click coordinates.

And beyond that: when you look into your other method --- the code to draw points is **commented out**.

Suggestion: step back; don't try to do 5 things at the same time. Write the code it takes to

- fetch mouse coordinates after a click
- draw circles around that coordinate

and get **that** to work. Forget about drawing lines, shapes, whatever *for now*.

And when you have a class that does nothing but that click+draw circles; then create a **new** class, where you add more features. Your "real" problem right now is that you started working on various features; and that your attempts to "integrate" them into a single class left you with something that is confusing, and not surprising ... not working!

Long story short: forgot about that strange logic that you have in your code right now to "toggle" between drawing points and lines. Draw points. And then, when that works ... add some radio buttons; or a drop down menu and use **that** to control if you want to draw lines or points. Don't make that "implicit" by toggling booleans in your event handler code!

Comment: As you're answer is very constructive and elaborated would you mind including my comment? (if it is true)
To me it also looks like a logic mistake as the `mouseClicked` will never do something after the first click if you look at the variables `drawPoint` and `drawLine` and the way they are checked in MouseClicked.

Comment: @Nico: I reworded a bit, and added. Thanks for the input ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`boolean drawPoint = true;`
 `boolean drawLine = false;` cause it to print the first time. After that both are set to true so it will not change coordinates.